# Checks if the execution of a stored procedure could modify data

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I would like to implement a WCF service with the scope to retrieve some data from a database.

The data is retrieved executing a stored procedure. Data is returned in xml format.

Practically, my service contains a method which one parameter specifying the name of the stored procedures to execute and, if necessary, some input parameters.

For security, I would like to check if the execution of the stored procedure passed as input could modify the data into the DB.

Let's do a simple example. I, a malicious user, find out how this service works, and call my method like this:

```
 ExecuteStoredProcedureToGetData("proc_InsertNewRow", "<XML><User Id="VeryBadBoy"/></XML>");
```

Is there a mechanism that I can use to check if `proc_InsertNewRow` modifies the database, working with C#, ADO.NET and SQL Server.

The logic I would give my implementation should be like this: I'm designed to retrieve some data, not to modify the data. I don't execute this stored procedure.

**EDIT**: I'll try to explain it better. My system generates a lot of data. Between the client and the server it was decided to add a new layer, my WCF service. So, when the client requests some data, the server forwards the data to my service passing the name of the stored procedure.

Ex. user opens the Products screen -> call to server `GetProducts()` -> call to WCF Service `ExecuteStoredProcedure("proc_GetProducts")`.

The check if the call to `ExecuteStoredProcedure` modifies the data is an additional check (or maybe an Xy problem as someone as defined) I want to do because I don't want that someone uses my general purpose method to alter the data.

Comment: Would it be an option to work with specific SQL Server permissions for the database user executing the procedures?

Comment: How is it that you have stored procedures that you don't know what they do?   This question sounds like one big misconception about stored procedures and security.

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't know the stored procedures installed. But anyway I want to avoid that someone uses the service in a way that is not the nominal working.

Comment: You could execute the procedures in a transaction and always force a rollback. That may not be 100% foolproof but it would be a good start. But, really you should be adding authentication/authorization to your service.

Comment: If *you* don't know what the stored procedures in *your(?)* database do, why are you giving users who you don't trust access to them? Normally the application controls what stored procedure (SQL) is called for a specific task; how/why is the user choosing what SP to call?

Comment: You're allowing the client to specify the stored procedure name?

Comment: Ok, but HOW do you not know the stored procedures??   You're being trusted to write this WCF, but not trusted to be told what the stored procedures are?   I really can't imagine a real world situation that disfunctional.   Unless... is this for the federal government?

Comment: If this isn't an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) I don't know what would be.

Comment: The WCF should be a transparent list of methods the client can call, to do certain tasks. Authorisations should be required to perform the task at hand. This should be independent of any database implementation - the client does not, and should not, need to know whether there is any database behind the service, let alone be able to call specific procedures from it. That's the whole point of a service. if you're just going to allow them to name a procedure, why not grant SQL access directly?? It comes to the same thing really.

Comment: You could do some crude regex find on a copy of the SQL used for the procedure to find out if it contains any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements and prevent access on that basis, but I kinda think your security model ought to be a little more sophisticated than that, with some role-based / claims-based rules in place. What's the purpose of this service meant to be??

Comment: This concept needs a 100% redesign. Using a webservice to receive a stored procedure name to execute is just horrific. The worst part of it for me is that you understand how truly horrible it is but you are trying to figure out how to make it less vulnerable. Redesign this nightmare into what webservices are intended to do, provide an access point for a very specific task. Blindly executing a stored procedure is NOT a specific task.

Answer (score 2):

Although you've asked about *Y*, I'm going to go ahead and address *X*.

Trying to program your WCF to pre-parse every stored procedure name that gets passed to it, *every time*, is a terrible idea.   It will be error-prone, bad for performance, and it's just not the right way or even right place to handle security.

I'd even go so far as to say that having a single WCF method to generically handle all stored procedure calls is also not the right way to do things, but that's even more tangential to your question.

The right way to do what you want is to find out from your database owners exactly which procedures the WCF users should be allowed to execute, and then program the WCF to only execute those procedures and return some kind of error/warning when the users tries to execute anything that is not on that list.

If you are concerned that the database owners may want to add new procedures in the future that are ok to use, they can keep the list of allowed procedures in a table, and you can just query that table each time a procedure call comes in.

But, disregarding your actual question even further, the BEST way to handle this is not to handle it at all...in the WCF.  The Right Place to handle database security is **in the database**. The WCF should be given a specific user account to access the database.   The Database Guys should be responsible for giving that user account the correct permissions to the procedures in their database.  The only thing you should be responsible for in the WCF is handling any permissions errors returned by the database.